# OpenCV calibrateCamera doesn't converge to correct solution (projector calibration)

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm trying to use `cv::calibrateCamera` to calibrate a camera+projector system. While it seems to work sometimes, in many cases the estimated solution seems to be pretty far from the correct one.

Here is a code sample which shows the problem (all data included - therefore it's quite big)

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

cv::Mat calculateTransformation(cv::Mat translationVec, cv::Mat rotationVec) {
    cv::Mat rotationMat3x3;
    cv::Rodrigues(rotationVec, rotationMat3x3);
    cv::Mat rotationMat = cv::Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64F);
    rotationMat3x3.copyTo(rotationMat(cv::Rect(0, 0, 3, 3)));

    cv::Mat translationMat = cv::Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_64F);
    translationVec.copyTo(translationMat(cv::Rect(3, 0, 1, 3)));

    return translationMat * rotationMat;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> image_points;
    std::vector<cv::Point3f> object_points;

    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(880.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1200.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1280.0f, 940.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(880.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1200.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1280.0f, 860.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(880.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1200.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1280.0f, 780.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(880.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1200.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1280.0f, 700.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(880.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1200.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1280.0f, 620.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(880.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1200.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(880.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1280.0f, 460.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1280.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1200.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(880.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 380.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(880.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 300.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1280.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1200.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1120.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 220.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1280.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1200.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(800.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(720.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(640.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(560.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(480.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(400.0f, 140.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1040.0f, 540.0f));
    image_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(960.0f, 460.0f));

    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0671159000000000f, -0.0530089000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0572335000000000f, -0.0531021000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0473920000000000f, -0.0531268000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0375422000000000f, -0.0531293000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0277093000000000f, -0.0532232000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0179416000000000f, -0.0532900000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.00818986000000000f, -0.0533080000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00159555000000000f, -0.0533734000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0113126000000000f, -0.0534102000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0210113000000000f, -0.0534688000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0307716000000000f, -0.0535300000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0404079000000000f, -0.0535600000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0668703000000000f, -0.0429498000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0569997000000000f, -0.0430325000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0471452000000000f, -0.0430930000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0373059000000000f, -0.0431530000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0274813000000000f, -0.0432117000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0176713000000000f, -0.0432687000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.00790218000000000f, -0.0433224000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00190183000000000f, -0.0433762000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0116116000000000f, -0.0434242000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0213028000000000f, -0.0434700000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0310283000000000f, -0.0435404000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0406556000000000f, -0.0436058000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0666877000000000f, -0.0329366000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0568031000000000f, -0.0329860000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0469101000000000f, -0.0330818000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0370300000000000f, -0.0331543000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0272122000000000f, -0.0332004000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0173840000000000f, -0.0332688000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.00759575000000000f, -0.0333343000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00215042000000000f, -0.0334201000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0119054000000000f, -0.0334816000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0215901000000000f, -0.0335390000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0313087000000000f, -0.0336208000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0409288000000000f, -0.0336740000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0664698000000000f, -0.0228786000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0565702000000000f, -0.0229386000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0466851000000000f, -0.0230437000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0367625000000000f, -0.0230813000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0269267000000000f, -0.0231839000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0171296000000000f, -0.0232845000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.00732099000000000f, -0.0232912000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00244503000000000f, -0.0234120000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0121943000000000f, -0.0235079000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0218997000000000f, -0.0235779000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0316661000000000f, -0.0236490000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0413080000000000f, -0.0237153000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0662403000000000f, -0.0127937000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0563243000000000f, -0.0128856000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0464450000000000f, -0.0129539000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0365046000000000f, -0.0130461000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0266992000000000f, -0.0131572000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0168820000000000f, -0.0132217000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.00702858000000000f, -0.0133096000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00273311000000000f, -0.0134175000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0222048000000000f, -0.0135829000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0124779000000000f, -0.0135008000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0319668000000000f, -0.0136414000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0416578000000000f, -0.0137210000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0660230000000000f, -0.00272328000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0560886000000000f, -0.00280125000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0461911000000000f, -0.00292352000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0362558000000000f, -0.00302379000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0264298000000000f, -0.00309841000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0165924000000000f, -0.00321897000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.00674314000000000f, -0.00331641000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0322628000000000f, -0.00369330000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0225310000000000f, -0.00360024000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0558388000000000f, 0.00733873000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0657448000000000f, 0.00744612000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0458967000000000f, 0.00723106000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0261183000000000f, 0.00701760000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0359654000000000f, 0.00710082000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0162843000000000f, 0.00688856000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0228789000000000f, 0.00646718000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.00641300000000000f, 0.00678188000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0131059000000000f, 0.00657206000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0422672000000000f, 0.00628497000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0231953000000000f, 0.0165035000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0425539000000000f, 0.0162757000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0328968000000000f, 0.0163892000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0133982000000000f, 0.0166424000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.00611577000000000f, 0.0168486000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0160094000000000f, 0.0169642000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00368791000000000f, 0.0167334000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0357336000000000f, 0.0171710000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0258655000000000f, 0.0170562000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0456858000000000f, 0.0173090000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0655273000000000f, 0.0175171000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0555765000000000f, 0.0174012000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0235599000000000f, 0.0266047000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0137369000000000f, 0.0267060000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00400251000000000f, 0.0268771000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.00579988000000000f, 0.0269546000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0156666000000000f, 0.0270784000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0255455000000000f, 0.0272245000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0354855000000000f, 0.0273244000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0454115000000000f, 0.0274243000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0553239000000000f, 0.0275921000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0652735000000000f, 0.0276931000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0432836000000000f, 0.0364607000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0335970000000000f, 0.0365698000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0239205000000000f, 0.0367035000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0140970000000000f, 0.0368368000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00436217000000000f, 0.0369936000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0152808000000000f, 0.0372578000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0252343000000000f, 0.0373656000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0351242000000000f, 0.0374961000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0450986000000000f, 0.0376261000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0550835000000000f, 0.0377566000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0649853000000000f, 0.0379110000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0436747000000000f, 0.0466393000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0339311000000000f, 0.0467559000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0144269000000000f, 0.0470150000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00466523000000000f, 0.0471564000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0150279000000000f, 0.0474823000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0248820000000000f, 0.0475522000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0348463000000000f, 0.0476901000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0447968000000000f, 0.0478509000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0547835000000000f, 0.0479670000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(-0.0647592000000000f, 0.0481078000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00301477000000000f, -0.00341146000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.0128075000000000f, -0.00350684000000000f, 0.0f));
    object_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(0.00336785000000000f, 0.00670002000000000f, 0.0f));

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> all_image_points;
    all_image_points.push_back(image_points);
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>> all_object_points;
    all_object_points.push_back(object_points);

    cv::Mat camera_mat = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
    cv::Mat dist_coeffs = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 1, CV_64F);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> tvecs;

    double reprojection_error = cv::calibrateCamera(all_object_points, all_image_points, cv::Size(1920, 1080), camera_mat, dist_coeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
    std::cout << "Reprojection error: " << reprojection_error << std::endl;

    cv::Mat transformation = calculateTransformation(tvecs.front(), rvecs.front());
    cv::Mat origin = cv::Mat::zeros(4, 1, CV_64F);
    origin.at<double>(3, 0) = 1.0;
    std::cout << "distance to board: " << cv::norm(transformation * origin) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

- The object points are measured in meters
- The distance to the board should be roughly 0.64 meters (estimated are 1.7 meters)
- The radial distortion parameter `k2` has a value above 200 which is kind of weird
- I've visualized my input data using matlab to verify that the correspondences are correct
- I know that I get more robust solutions with multiple captures but the posted data seem to influence the solution quite heavily. Made two captures which produced a solution which seemed right, added another capture (posted data) which led to a wrong solution.
- I guess the data is a bit more noisy then regular calibration data because I can't capture the data directly (it's a projector calibration) but need to use a camera which detects an projected pattern

If someone wants to visualize the data using matlab: I've simpliy used

```
plot3([image_points(1,:);object_points(1,:) * 10000], [image_points(2,:);object_points(2,:) * -10000], [zeros(1, 125); ones(1, 125)], 'b-')
```

so you get one line per correspondence between object and image point.

If more information is needed just post a comment.

Comment: So you get the right parameters some of the time? Have you tried initializing the camera matrix with a guess and using CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS? I've also had more success in the past with the matlab camera calibration toolbox, maybe compare to what results you get there

Comment: Yes sometime I get correct parameters (intrinsic and extrinsic). In my actual implementation I'm using `initCameraMatrix2D` as initial guess - that seem to improve it in some cases but it still occures quite often. I also tried to compare the behavior with the matlab calibration toolbox but wasn't able to figure out how to put in my correspondences directly (if you can give me a hint that would be awesome too).

Comment: "So you get the right parameters some of the time?" - After thinking about it: I sometimes get the correct parameters with different data - Hope this is less ambiguous

Comment: If I understood correctly, you're trying to calibrate camera using only one rig (one surface)? If yes, I'm afraid you need at least two non-planar surfaces and its projections to have successful calibration. One rig is not enough, even from theoretical side. So it is not the matter of the points (in your example 125), but usage of different views. And offtopic: +1 for the example that can be directly pasted to visual studio to test the issue.

Comment: @marol: Thanks for your comment. Actually that was one thing I was thinking about - good to have a definitive answer to that. But I'm still wondering why the calibration didn't work when I tried to capture the pattern from different distances. I was only able to move it ~10 cm because of the depth of field. I guess more movement leads to better results? Will definitely try that on monday and give you feedback - If this will solve it you can also post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposition is to use different **non-coplanar** rigs (surfaces)  in camera calibration process. The algorithm opencv uses definitely need at least two different views to perform good calibration. If it possible, provide several views with different angles (2 is just a starting point, 10 is desirable). I'm not 100% sure now, but I think non-planar requirement is *sine qua non* condition, namely you cannot obtain good results with coplanar views (because in fact they are different only according to the scale factor so in some words we can say they are isomorphic  in terms of projection geometry).

And one comment to projection error - in tested case is around 0.65 what seems to be accurate... But here's the tricky part - because we calibrate the camera using only one rig, so by definition, when opencv re project back points, it has only one surface to reproject to. In other words, the calibration error is small and it is greater than zero only because there is a noise giving point's projections.

Comment: seems like this was actually the problem. If someone wants more details => Zhang described some of the issues in his work (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/Papers/TR98-71.pdf)